# Analyze a file and call function

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, call

I wrote a batch script and I have a little problem.

Basically, I have a file "ip_file.txt" with IP (% ip_file%).
My script parses this file, and, based on the IP, call a particular program.

Here's how I wrote the script, but it does not work.

```
REM START SCRIPT BASE

for /f %%i in (%ip_file%) do ( 
IF %%a.%%b.==10.10 call :script_1 %%i 
IF %%a.%%b.==192.168 call :script_2 %%i 
) 
else ( call :script_0 %%i) 

REM END SCRIPT BASE
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you expect to be in %%a and %%b? Where you define them?

Comment: It's my mistake. Problem solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the contents of the file referenced by `%ip_file%` is a list of IPv4 addresses (or at least that each line begins with an IPv4 address), you can use `tokens` and `delims` to split on `.`.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

REM // START MAIN RUNTIME

set "ip_file=path\to\ip_file.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%ip_file%") do ( 

    if "%%a.%%b"=="10.10" (

        call :script_1 %%a.%%b.%%c.%%d

    ) else if "%%a.%%b"=="192.168" (

        call :script_2 %%a.%%b.%%c.%%d

    ) else call :script_0 %%a.%%b.%%c.%%d
)

goto :EOF
REM // END MAIN RUNTIME

:script_0 <ip>
rem // catch-all
goto :EOF

:script_1 <ip>
rem // handle 10.10 addresses
goto :EOF

:script_2 <ip>
rem // handle 192.168 addresses
goto :EOF
```

It should also be noted, when you `call :label` where label begins with a colon, you are calling a subroutine within the same batch script.  If you are indeed calling external batch scripts, leave off the colons.

Comment: I add this : set ip=%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d so now I use !ip! to call my script . Than you again

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%i in (%ip_file%) do (
set ip=%%i 
if %ip:~0,5%==10.10 call :script_1 %%i 
if %ip:~0,7%==192.168 call :script_2 %%i 
) 
else ( call :script_0 %%i)
```

Comment: This is broken as well.  `!ip:~0,n!` needs delayed expansion (along with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) if using this substring extraction method. Also, `else` needs to be beside an `if` statement's closing parenthetical

Comment: Finally I decided to use tokens  .  A big Thank you for the answer and the advices.